# ShortString in Unicode Version

Tags: string, delphi, unicode

In old Delphi versions (ANSI string), ShortStrings:

```
var Str: String[30];
```

Could be used to reduce memory cost and still had ANSI Encoding.

In current Unicode Versions, Is ShortString like above, aliased to some Unicode encoded version? 
Does the advantage of this practice still exists to reduce memory cost?

Comment: why wasting 5 minutes for forum when you can just learn it in one minute ? `var s: string[10]; begin WriteLn(SizeOf(s):10, SizeOf(s[1]));`

Comment: @Arioch'The That approach of trial and error can also "prove" that coins always land with heads up. I never like to recommend trial and error. For example, your approach does not discover the hidden compiler option that makes short strings use Unicode characters. Granted there is no such option, but trial and error as you propose would not reveal it, were it to exist.

Comment: Funny the part about reducing memory cost using short strings. A few days ago I did just the opposite: Replacing short strings with long strings to reduce memory footprint. Was I successful at that? You bet! I got a whole bunch of instances down to a fraction of their original memory footprint, including the memory for the long strings (if used at all). I have to mention that it was an pre-Unicode Delphi.

Comment: Thanks to share that, if the same happens to me, I'll share too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Delphi short string always uses the ANSI encoding, even in modern Unicode aware Delphi versions. They are considered a legacy data type and so Embarcadero elected not to make changes when it introduced Unicode.

For what it is worth, using a short string did not necessarily reduce memory costs. It would only do so if your strings were all close to the same length. If your strings had any significant variation in length, then using dynamic (a.k.a. long) strings would result in lower memory overhead.

I don't think that short strings were ever better than dynamic strings. They exist simply because they pre-date dynamic strings. Had dynamic strings been invented first, short strings would not exist. Indeed they do not exist in the new mobile compilers. In other words, just use dynamic strings.

Comment: I am asking because I am porting an old ANSI Application to Unicode version, and it was full of ShortString. I think I'll change them all to string.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be wise. Take care with any code at the boundaries of the program. Typically that would be code that writes/reads those strings to file.

Comment: I was going to do the wrong thing. I thought each character of ShortString became WideChar, Thank you very much!